# Use fgsl in fortran: how to compile with gfortran

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am trying to do something basic, but I can't find the relevant information on how to compile. I tried the following without success:

```
gfortran testintegral.f90 -lgsl -lgslcblas
testintegral.f90:19.6:
  use fgsl
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'fgsl.mod' for reading at (1): No such file
```

The file is taken from http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran:_FGSL#Beispiel:_Numerische_Integration (page in german but readily understandable) so I suppose it is OK.

Maybe the syntax of the compilation command is incorrect ?

---

EDIT:

I edit my initial post so as not to bury important information in the comments.

Those are the paths of the libraries:

```
sudo find -name '*libgsl.so*'
./usr/lib/libgsl.so.0
./usr/lib/libgsl.so.0.17.0
sudo find -name '*libgslcblas.so*'
./usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0
./usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
```

But I still got an error message when doing:

```
gfortran testintegral.f90 -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include/fgsl -lfgsl -lgsl -lgslcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: An English page: http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/.  How did you install fgsl?  I've used selected routines from source, in which case I just directly compiled with gfortran.  If another method installed a library, you have to be sure to include linker options `l` and perhaps `L`.   And maybe `I` to designate the directory for the module file.

Comment: Precisely like in the page you mention: `deb [arch=amd64] http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu trusty stable` in my sources.list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-I` flag. For example,

```
gfortran -I/usr/local/fgsl/include testintegral.f90 -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

All the .mod files in that directory are then included.

EDIT: See also comments below.

Comment: It'll probably also need a `-lfgsl` before the `-lgsl` to build against the FGSL interface routines.

Comment: With a `find` I found (!) my lfgsl module to be in `/usr/include/fgsl` which I put instead of `/usr/local/fgsl/include`. But then I have the following problem : `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Locations of the libraries are specified with the `-L` flag, .e.g. `gfortran -L/usr/gsl/lib -L/usr/fgsl/lib ...`.

Comment: I still have the same issue with: `gfortran -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include/fgsl testintegral.f90 -lfgsl -lgsl -lgslcblas`. I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libgsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: What is the location of libgsl.so and libgslcblas.so?

Comment: It searches for files ending with .so, which seem to be missing in your case. You can either specify the full path to the library, `gfortran ... /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0`, and forget the `-L` flag, or make the necessary symbolic links first, `ln -sv libgsl.so{.0,}`, etc.

Comment: @RaulLaasner Great, now it works ! How is it so that it is so complicated ? And why do I have to manually create the links ? I installed those libraries with `sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl` is it not the standard procedure ? I feel like I want to do something basic, but nevertheless obscure and undocumented.

Comment: @bela83 If you're running Ubuntu, then I think installing `libgsl0-dev`  automatically creates the links. See [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for a general information about using shared libraries, in particular Sec. 3.1.1 might be relevant to the current discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation of a file containing modules in gfortran produces two file types: The source file `foo.f90` is translated into `foo.o`.  If `foo.f90` contains the modules `bar` and `baz`, then `bar.mod` and `baz.mod` are also generated.  They contain the interface information for these modules.  Note that there is no required mapping between module and file names (although programming guildelines may require this).

When the statement `use fsgl` is found, the interface information is read from `fsgl.mod`.  If that file is not found, you get the error message

```
Can't open module file 'fgsl.mod' for reading at (1): No such file
```

So, you have to change your order of compilation (possibly through changing a `Makefile`).

Comment: Dear @tkoenig thanks ! But I don't even use a Makefile, it really is basic. How would I do what you suggest at command line ? fgsl is the Fortran GNU Scientific Library, I installed it through a repo, so I have the libraries on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

1) the easiest way is

```
gfortran testintegral.f90 -I/usr/local/include/fgsl -lfgsl
```

2) this also works

```
gfortran -I/usr/local/include/fgsl testintegral.f90 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

3) I read the log of the `make check` in the package, the developer used such a way

```
gfortran -I/usr/local/include/fgsl -g -O2 -c -o test.o testintegral.f90
/bin/bash /path/.../fgsl-1.3.0/libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran -g -O2   -o test test.o /usr/local/lib/libfgsl.la -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

**UPDATE:**

First check the linkers for `fgsl`

```
pkg-config --libs fgsl
```

probably will get something like this

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lfgsl -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Then you put the linkers, works for all the cases!

```
gfortran -I/usr/include/fgsl example.f90 -lfgsl -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

**UPDATE:** I answered too soon, here is the best universal method I found:

```
gfortran `pkg-config --cflags fgsl` testintegral.f90 -o integral `pkg-config --libs fgsl`
```